# Distribution Provisioning Profiles not valid

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my iOS application to iTunes Connect. When I run *Product-> Build For->Build for Archiving* I get this error:

> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

I've tried recreating and downloaded my certificates for both Development and Distribution and redownloaded the *Development Provisioning Profile* and *Distribution Provisioning Profile*. In the Organizer no errors are displayed under *Provisioning Profiles*. When I select my *Distribution Provisioning Profile* it has the following text in the top:

> Devices: This profile cannot be installed on devices

Is this a problem? Except from this, I do not have any clue of what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have this already, but have you set the code signing in your Target with the proper certificate that you downloaded?

Comment: I'm not sure. Where can I do that?

Comment: @DennisMadsen In XCode in the project navigator, click on your .xcodeproject, that will show a new window, with PROJECT and TARGETS click on your project name under TARGETS and select Build Settings, then go to the Code Signing section, and in Code Signing Identity select your distribution certificate from the list. Hope that helps.